# AVR GCC - Use static library - undefined reference errors

Tags: c, avr, atmega, avr-gcc

I'm currently trying to read values from a temperature sensor (Dallas ds18b20) with an AVR atmega328p. In order to read values, I need to import an external library ([using this one](https://github.com/Jacajack/avr-ds18b20)). I have used the Makefile in the external repository to create a static library (`libds18b20.a` in `lib` directory). I also added the header files to my own source. I have the following Makefile:

```
PORT_ID=/dev/ttyACM0
MCU=atmega328p
F_CPU=1200000
CC=avr-gcc
PROGRAMMER_ID=stk500v1
OBJCOPY=avr-objcopy
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall -g -Os -mmcu=${MCU} -DF_CPU=${F_CPU} -I.
TARGET=main
SRCS=main.c
BAUD_RATE=19200
PATH_DS18B20=./lib

all:
    ${CC} -L ${PATH_DS18B20} ${CFLAGS} -o ${TARGET}.bin ${SRCS}
    ${OBJCOPY} -j .text -j .data -O ihex ${TARGET}.bin ${TARGET}.hex

flash:
    avrdude -v -P ${PORT_ID} -b ${BAUD_RATE} -c ${PROGRAMMER_ID} -p ${MCU} -U flash:w:${TARGET}.hex

clean:
    rm -f *.bin *.hex
```

However, when I try to run this Makefile I got the following errors (output partially omitted):

```
/main.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `ds18b20convert'
/main.c:60: undefined reference to `ds18b20read'
```

These functions are defined in the headers files. I'm expecting that the static library is not properly linked. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Look in `${PATH_DS18B20}` there should be a library there named libsomething.{a,so} ... add -lsomething to your  $CC line

Comment: @technosaurus I'm sure that here is a libds18b20.a file in there. I also tried to add the full path which also doesn't work

Comment: Here's the full source https://github.com/markvdlaan93/avr-temperature-monitoring/tree/master/src/temperature

Comment: It seems like you found an alternative, but simply adding `-lds18b20` to the $CC line would have worked too.  Conventionally those are added to $LFLAGS or $LDFLAGS variables and may include the full relative paths to static libraries like you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by omitting the `-L` flag and put the path directly behind the `${SRCS}`-variable including the name of the static library:

```
PORT_ID=/dev/ttyACM0
MCU=atmega328p
F_CPU=1200000
CC=avr-gcc
PROGRAMMER_ID=stk500v1
OBJCOPY=avr-objcopy
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall -g -Os -mmcu=${MCU} -DF_CPU=${F_CPU} -I.
TARGET=main
SRCS=main.c
BAUD_RATE=19200
PATH_DS18B20=./lib/libds18b20.a

all:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o ${TARGET}.bin ${SRCS} ${PATH_DS18B20}
    ${OBJCOPY} -j .text -j .data -O ihex ${TARGET}.bin ${TARGET}.hex

flash:
    avrdude -v -P ${PORT_ID} -b ${BAUD_RATE} -c ${PROGRAMMER_ID} -p ${MCU} -U flash:w:${TARGET}.hex

clean:
    rm -f *.bin *.hex
```